# Non-monotonic output of Constrained Optimisation in R

Tags: r, mathematical-optimization

### Problem

The constOptim function is R is giving me a set of parameter estimates. These parameter estimates are spending values at 12 different points in the year and should be monotonically decreasing.

I need them to be monotonic and for the gaps between each parameter to right for the application I have in mind. For the purposes of this the pattern in spending values is important and not the absolute values. I guess in optimization terms this means I need the tolerance to be small compared to the differences in parameter estimates.

### Minimal Working Example (with simple Utility Function)

```
# Initial Parameters and Functions
Budget          = 1
NumberOfPeriods = 12
rho = 0.996
Utility_Function <- function(x){ x^0.5 }
Time_Array = seq(0,NumberOfPeriods-1)

# Value Function at start of time.
ValueFunctionAtTime1   = function(X){
  Frame                = data.frame(X, time = Time_Array)
  Frame$Util           = apply(Frame, 1, function(Frame) Utility_Function(Frame["X"]))
  Frame$DiscountedUtil = apply(Frame, 1, function(Frame) Frame["Util"] * rho^(Frame["time"])) 
  return(sum(Frame$DiscountedUtil))
}

# The sum of all spending in the year should be less than than the annual budget.
# This gives the ui and ci arguments
Sum_Of_Annual_Spends   = c(rep(-1,NumberOfPeriods))

# The starting values for optimisation is an equal expenditure in each period.
# The denominator is multiplied by 1.1 to avoid an initial values out of range error.
InitialGuesses         = rep(Budget/(NumberOfPeriods*1.1), NumberOfPeriods)

# Optimisation
Optimal_Spending    = constrOptim(InitialGuesses,
                                  function(X) -ValueFunctionAtTime1(X),
                                  NULL,
                                  ui = Sum_Of_Annual_Spends,
                                  ci = -Budget,
                                  outer.iterations = 100,
                                  outer.eps = 1e-10)$par
```

### The result:

The output of the function is not monotonic.

```
plot( Time_Array , Optimal_Spending)
```

[image: NonMonotonic Output of constOptim Function]

### My attempts at fixing it

I have tried:

- Increasing the tolerance (This is above in the code with `outer.eps = 1e-10`)
- Increasing the amount of iterations (This is above in the code with `outer.iterations = 100`)
- Improving the quality of the initial parameter values. I did this with my actual case (the same but with a much more complicated utility function) but did not solve the problem.
- Scaling the problem through either increasing the Budget or multiplying the utility function by a scalar.

### Other questions on constOptim

Other SO questions focus on difficulties in writing the constraints for constOptim such as:

1. [Setting constraints in constrOptim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16345271/setting-constraints-in-constroptim)
2. [Constrain Optimisation Problems in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666120/constrain-optimisation-problems-in-r)

I have not found anything examining tolerances or dissatisfaction with the output.

Comment: Did you try forcing a gradient on your function (and specifying a different `optim` method)? I haven't used `constrOptim` but that would seem to be a thing to try. That, or change your contstraint matrix and vector (ui, ci) so there's a relationship between every pair of months.

Comment: Hi @CarlWitthoft, I haven't a gradient basically because I don't know a great deal about optimisation theory and am not confident to specify gradients. I also think that there should be a way to fix this without gradients (although it may take longer). As for other optim packages, I normally use OptimX but cannot in this case as it would result in every parameter being infinite. I need to specify in the optimisation that       x1 + x2 + ... + x_n < Budget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't exactly an answer, but it's longer than a comment and should be helpful.

I think your problem has an analytical solution -- that's good to know if you're testing an optimization algorithm.

Here it is when the budget is fixed to 1.0.

```
analytical.solution <- function(rho=0.9, T=10) {
    sapply(seq_len(T) - 1, function(t) (rho ^ (2*t)) * (1 - rho^2) / (1 - rho^(2*T)))
}
sum(analytical.solution())  # Should be 1.0, i.e. the budget
```

Here the consumer consumes in periods {0, 1, ..., T-1}. The solution is indeed monotonically decreasing with the time index. I got this by setting up a Lagrangian and working with the first-order conditions.

EDIT:

I rewrote your code and everything seems to work correctly: constrOptim gives a solution that agrees with my analytical solution. The budget is fixed at 1.

```
analytical.solution <- function(rho=0.9, T=10) {
    sapply(seq_len(T) - 1, function(t) (rho ^ (2*t)) * (1 - rho^2) / (1 - rho^(2*T)))
}
candidate.solution <- analytical.solution()
sum(candidate.solution)  # Should be 1.0, i.e. the budget

objfn <- function(x, rho=0.9, T=10) {
    stopifnot(length(x) == T)
    sum(sqrt(x) * rho ^ (seq_len(T) - 1))
}
objfn.grad <- function(x, rho=0.9, T=10) {
    rho ^ (seq_len(T) - 1) * 0.5 * (1/sqrt(x))
}

## Sanity check the gradient
library(numDeriv)
all.equal(grad(objfn, candidate.solution), objfn.grad(candidate.solution))  # True

ui <- rbind(matrix(data=-1, nrow=1, ncol=10), diag(10))  # First row: budget constraint; other rows: x >= 0
ci <- c(-1, rep(10^-8, 10))
all(ui %*% candidate.solution - ci >= 0)  # True, the candidate solution is admissible
result1 <- constrOptim(theta=rep(0.01, 10), f=objfn, ui=ui, ci=ci, grad=objfn.grad, control=list(fnscale=-1))
round(abs(result1$par - candidate.solution), 4)  # Essentially zero
result2 <- constrOptim(theta=candidate.solution, f=objfn, ui=ui, ci=ci, grad=objfn.grad, control=list(fnscale=-1))
round(abs(result2$par - candidate.solution), 4)  # Essentially zero
```

Follow-up about gradients:

The optimization seems to work even with grad=NULL, which means there's probably a bug in your code. Look at this:

```
result3 <- constrOptim(theta=rep(0.01, 10), f=objfn, ui=ui, ci=ci, grad=NULL, control=list(fnscale=-1))
round(abs(result3$par - candidate.solution), 4)  # Still very close to zero
result4 <- constrOptim(theta=c(10^-6, 1-10*10^-6, rep(10^-6, 8)), f=objfn, ui=ui, ci=ci, grad=NULL, control=list(fnscale=-1))
round(abs(result4$par - candidate.solution), 4)  # Still very close to zero
```

Follow-up about rho=0.996 case:

As rho->1 the solution should converge to rep(1/T, T) -- that explains why even small errors by constrOptim have a noticeable effect on whether or not the output is monotonically decreasing.

When rho=0.996 it seems that the tuning parameter affects constrOptim's output enough to change monotonicity -- see below:

```
candidate.solution <- analytical.solution(rho=0.996)
candidate.solution  # Should be close to rep(1/10, 10) as discount factor is close to 1.0

result5 <- constrOptim(theta=c(10^-6, 1-10*10^-6, rep(10^-6, 8)), f=objfn,
                       ui=ui, ci=ci, grad=objfn.grad, control=list(fnscale=-1), rho=0.996)
round(abs(result5$par - candidate.solution), 4)
plot(result5$par)  # Looks nice when we used objfn.grad, as you pointed out

play.with.tuning.parameter <- function(mu) {
    result <- constrOptim(theta=c(10^-6, 1-10*10^-6, rep(10^-6, 8)), f=objfn,
                          mu=mu, outer.iterations=200, outer.eps = 1e-08,
                          ui=ui, ci=ci, grad=NULL, control=list(fnscale=-1), rho=0.996)
    return(mean(diff(result$par) < 0))
}

candidate.mus <- seq(0.01, 1, 0.01)
fraction.decreasing <- sapply(candidate.mus, play.with.tuning.parameter)
candidate.mus[fraction.decreasing == max(fraction.decreasing)]  # A few little clusters at 1.0
plot(candidate.mus, fraction.decreasing)  # ...but very noisy

result6 <- constrOptim(theta=c(10^-6, 1-10*10^-6, rep(10^-6, 8)), f=objfn,
                          mu=candidate.mus[which.max(fraction.decreasing)], outer.iterations=200, outer.eps = 1e-08,
                          ui=ui, ci=ci, grad=NULL, control=list(fnscale=-1), rho=0.996)
plot(result6$par)
round(abs(result6$par - candidate.solution), 4)
```

When you pick the right tuning parameter, you get a monotonically decreasing result even without the gradient.

Comment: Yep - like I was guessing, extending ci and ui to a matrix and vector was a big part of it.

Comment: Thanks Adrian. As I understand it the problem is solved through the supply of a gradient expression as @CarlWitthoft alluded to. It would be great if there was a way that didn't require gradients but I suppose there is not. I don't think the ui and ci played a large role as the additional non negativity constraints would never bind. Imposing these additional constraints without the gradient function does not solve the problem while the gradient functions do (to see this you need rho = 0.996). It is good to have the constraints though for completeness. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Stuart the gradient isn't necessary -- see my follow-up edit above.

Comment: @Adrian I agree in the rho = 0.9 case. Running your code the round(abs(...)) statement gives very low errors and when you plot it you get a monotonic pattern. Changing only rho to 0.996 in your code however and results in higher errors and a non monotonic pattern `plot(1:10, result4$par)'. I still think the gradient is the solution. The gradient is just not critical in cases where rho is low.

Comment: @Stuart I see, I do get the same results as you with rho=0.996. The constrOptim tuning parameter affects the output, however -- I'll add an example at the bottom of my reply.

Comment: @Adrian. I think you are right. So this problem can be solved by either adding a gradient or by calibrating the tuning parameter. Thank you very much for all of your help, it is much appreciated.